# Priority of function execution in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, order-of-execution

I don't understand why a second function call ( after a function body ) has a priority over the one inside of a body ?

```
function a(){
  var num = 5;
  console.log( ++num );
  setTimeout( a, 100 );
};
setTimeout(a,2000)
```

Comment: What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: Were you supposed to write "function a() {...}();" (note the final parentheses)? Your code doesn't call the function before the final line.

Comment: I just want to know why one call is waiting for the other ? Then I'll be able to predict behaviour.

Comment: Are you confused by the fact that `num` never seems to change? If so, it's because you're reinitializaing a new variable every time `a` is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In chronological order:

- you are defining function `a` **without** calling it
- you are scheduling `a` to be invoked after two seconds: `setTimeout(a,2000)`
- it is called
- when it is called, it schedules itself for invocation after 100 milliseconds

Your code basically sleeps for 2 seconds and then executes `a` with 100 millisecond pauses<sup>[*]</sup>.

However judging by your context you are asking what is the priority in the following situation:

```
setTimeout(a, 2000);
setTimeout(b, 100);
```

Well, most likely `b` will be called first (assuming there is no unpredictable pause between first and second line, e.g. due to overall OS performance problem).

If you use the same timeouts:

```
setTimeout(a, 100);
setTimeout(b, 100);
```

`a` will most likely be called first. However I don't think this is guaranteed and depends on the JS engine (whether it uses a strict FIFO list for upcoming events, what is the internal clock resolution, etc.)

<sup>[*] You can achieve *similar* behaviour by using `setInterval()` **once**.</sup>

Comment: I was going to +1, but please omit the `setInterval` part... It has very little to do here and can be confusing for carousel.

Comment: @MaxArt: moved to a smaller note. I don't think it is confusing, but agree that is not very related to the script

Answer (score 1):

The function `a` isn't called, just defined. The piece of code that is actually run is the definition of `a`, then `setTimeout(a,2000)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
function a () {
    var num = 5;
    console.log( ++num );
    setTimeout( a, 100 ); 
};
```

is a function body and after this we are calling. I do not think it is a hierarchy problem.